# What is content provider?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-syncadapter

I just followed tutorial in [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/index.html) to create sync adapter to provider feature "synchronization between local db with server db", and after bloody trial and error i managed to make it work (onPerformSync has called successfully).

And now for next step to create sync feature, from what i have read in several articles, I need to create a `content provider`. I already read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html but I still dont get it how does it work.

from this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html, it raised several questions in my head:

1. what `table` they are talking about? are they talking about sqlite table or some "another" table?
2. `content://user_dictionary/words` what uri is this? is this uri to table file where sqlite stored? if it's, how do I know mine? I mean where did my sqlite store table that I created?
3. from what I read (if i got it right), ContentProvider just like a repository. do they have same functionality? I already created my repository using anko https://gist.github.com/mockiemockiz/a552a669d28a3c90c144bc1542b86a5e , can I use that code / convert that code to be ContentProvider that able to tell sync adapter the data has changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just followed tutorial in developer.android.com to create sync adapter to provider feature "synchronization between local db with server db", and after bloody trial and error i managed to make it work (onPerformSync has called successfully).

FWIW, `SyncAdapter` is not especially popular.

> what table they are talking about?

The word "table" shows up 40 times on that page. We have no way of knowing which of those 40 concerns you, and they use the term in multiple ways.

> what uri is this?

That is a `Uri` pointing to a collection of data ("table") in the `user_dictionary` `ContentProvider`.

> is this uri to table file where sqlite stored?

That is for the developer of the `ContentProvider` to decide. The `ContentProvider` API does not stipulate where the data is stored. It could be stored in SQLite, or a JSON file, or whatever. *Convention* says that a collection of data exposed by a `ContentProvider` maps to a SQLite table or view, but that is not required.

> if it's, how do I know mine?

You know it is your `ContentProvider` if you used `user_dictionary` as your authority (see `android:authorities` in the `<provider>` element in the manifest).

> I mean where did my sqlite store table that I created?

That is up to you. `ContentProvider` has nothing to do with SQLite, unless *you* write code that ties a `ContentProvider` implementation to SQLite.

> ContentProvider just like a repository

Not really, at least in terms of how I use the term "repository". A `ContentProvider` is a wrapper around some data storage mechanism, to allow outside parties to have controlled access to that data.

> can I use that code / convert that code to be ContentProvider that able to tell sync adapter the data has changed?

That would be rather difficult. This is one of the reasons why few developers use `SyncAdapter`.

Comment: ahh ok, do i have another option other than using syncadapter? firestore? i dont think we are ready to migrating to use no-sql.

Comment: @Kakashi: "do i have another option other than using syncadapter?" -- you communicate with your server using whatever protocol your server supports (e.g., REST, GraphQL). You schedule the work using `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler`.